# Why the transition of electron from an excited state to metastable state in a lasing medium is radiation less?

Tags: laser, laser-interaction

When an electron transitions from an excited state to the metastable state, no radiation is emitted i.e. a radiationless transition.

My question is: Where does the energy difference between excited state and metastable state go?

Comment: I don't know the details, but my guess would be either *emission of a photon that is not taken into account in your model, because its frequency doesn't match the cavity, or *emission of a phonon

Answer (score 1):

It depends, there are different decay processes happening in a medium. Not all the decays are radiative (i.e., with emission of a photon).
Moreover, regarding photonic channel decay, non-induced transition provoke isotropic photon emission. In lasing you care about spontaneous emission over the cavity direction. Being the fraction of spontaneous emitted photons over the cavity direction negligible, and also considering non resonant photons (usually the transition to metastable states is done with non-resonant photons with the cavity...), these decays do not produce lasing effects.